# Check if Password exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1. Now I want to retrieve check if a certain password is already defined in the database. Here's my database schema

/* Accounts table */

```
Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('pharmacist_id')->unsigned()->index();
      $table->foreign('pharmacist_id')->references('id')->on('pharmacists')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->string('username')->unique();
      $table->string('password', 70);
      $table->string('rights');
      $table->rememberToken()
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

/* Pharmacists Table */

```
Schema::create('pharmacists', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('pharmacy_id')->unsigned()->index();
      $table->foreign('pharmacy_id')->references('id')->on('pharmacies')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->string('fname');
      $table->string('mname');
      $table->string('lname')
      $table->date('bdate');
      $table->string('email');
      $table->string('contact');
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now what I want is to check if a certain password is already defined in a certain pharmacy_id it looks something like this

```
$accounts = Account::whereHas('pharmacist', function($query) {
                    return $query->where('pharmacy_id', Auth::user()->id);
                })->where('password', $password)->get();
```

But it seems that the password is only being passed as a plain text and not encrypted. Also I tried using this method

```
where('password', bcrypt($password))
where('password', Hash::make($password))
where('password', Crypt::encrypt($password))
```

But none of this works. Any solution guys? I'm thinking of something like this and I'm not sure if this is possible

```
$is_valid = Auth::validate(array('pharmacist.pharmacy_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'password' => $value));
```

Because if I used the below code I can able to check if the user has inputted the valid password.

```
$is_valid = Auth::validate(array('id' => Auth::user()->id, 'password' => $value));
```

It's easy to check if the username and password match using the `Auth::validate` but the needed checking is to check if a certain pharmacist already inputted this specific password. So basically its kinda like looping in all the accounts and check if their password is the same as this specific password.

Here's what I have so far but this has some problem. If a certain pharmacy has 1000+ user then this will loop 1000x which is not optimized and not a good solution

```
$accounts = Account::whereHas('pharmacist', function($query) {
                    return $query->where('pharmacy_id', Auth::user()->id);
                })->get();


foreach($accounts as $account) {
    if (Hash::check($value, $account->password)) {
      // FOUND!!!
    }
}
```

To make it short

Pharmacy has many Pharmacists
Pharmacist has one account

Now I want to check if a certain Pharmacy has an account password of "certain password" so its like I need to check all account belonging to a certain pharmacists and that pharmacy belongs to a certain pharmacy

Comment: Password hash functions are supposed to be slow and resource intensive to crack, so ideally you shouldn't be able to implement this in any "optimal" way. Laravel uses Bcrypt by default, which is very cpu intensive, and adds an unique salt to each user. This is why you can't just generate a hash and select users having this hash from the DB - they might have the password, but they won't have the same salt.

Comment: What is the use of this in the first place? Why check whether a password is already used elsewhere?

Comment: I don´t really get what you are trying to achieve. If you want something to loop every password you already have your solution. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Initially I created a credential where in 1 pharmacy will have many pharmacist and each pharmacist will have its own account. Now client wants it to have 1 pharmacy and all pharmacist will use 1 account. And the only thing to identify this pharmacist is through their Password/PIN. So if they do some adding they need to input their PIN that way I will know who did what. But the only way to check the PIN is already existing is to get all password and check it one by one if password is existing

Comment: @Silencio Yes I was able to solve this but its not optimize.The drwback with my solution is that I need to loop each account and check their pass one by one.Problem is wen I hav around 1000 records this wil really slow down the performnce.Im looking for sumthing that is like a query that I don't need to loop everything its something like this
select * from account inner join pharmacists on (pharmacists.id = account.pharmacist.id) where pharamacists.pharmacy_id = 1 and account.password ={hash::make($password)|
now the problem is I cant hash my given password so that it will match wats in the db

Comment: To be quite blunt, that's a stupid requirement. Instead of complying with it, you should have talked them out of it.

Comment: @MadzmarUllang  I do not see a way to optimize this process if all you have to identify a single pharmacist is a password. As far as i see this is not an optimizátion problem. It is a desing-problem.

Comment: @Silencio It could be optimised by stopping to pretend that there's any "password" at all and just storing the *user ids* in plaintext... ;-(

Comment: @Silencio thats the last solution I'm thinking although this approach will have a big impact on my system since all the credential is checking on the password. I'm thinking of adding a new column that will hold all PIN and is encrypted only ung Crypt::encrypt so that I can easily decrypt this back whenever I need to

Comment: @MadzmarUllang I am still not sure... Are this really the limitations you have to work with? To me this seems very weird and i do not understand why you cannot just use a simple single-user-based login-system, if you want to know which user did what at any given time. The current solution is not good for your system as a whole and also not very userfriendly.

Comment: @Silencio Yes exactly my point. Its not user friendly and not flexible. This has many limitation and loop hole but everytime I bring up this kind of discussion this is the only answer I get from my employer " best to follow client lead now but I get what your saying. "

Answer (score 2):

> Client wants it to have 1 pharmacy and all pharmacist will use 1 account. And the only thing to identify this pharmacist is through their Password/PIN.

To put it bluntly: that's plain stupid.

A password is a secret which only the account holder knows. Nobody else is supposed to know the password. Not even the owner of the server. That's why you hash and salt passwords irretrievably to leave no trace of the plaintext password. The password is only used as a ***verification*** to prove the ***identity*** of the user.

The flow is:

1. user claims to be "X" *(identity)*
2. server ask *"if you're really X, what is the secret?"*
3. user *proves* their identity with their secret password

What you're doing is to reduce this to just one identifier. The user just claims to be "Bob" and as long as there is a "Bob" in your database you let them pass. But additionally you're doing this in the most technically backwards and slow way possible.

This also means every user will have to have a unique password. If a user chooses a password which already exists, you'll have to reject that password, telling the user to choose a different password. That signals to the user that someone else is using this password, and that they have just guessed somebody else's password and could impersonate them.

That's why there's a distinction between the indexable, knowable, de-duplicatable *id* and the secret *proof*.

Bad idea all around.

Comment: Exactly my idea dude. That's what I said and I suggested that this is not right and its prone to inconsistency and prone to many loop hole and user can log something and blame other for it since he knows that user pin already exists. I tried raising up this problem but client insist it that way :(

Comment: Since you're the one responsible for the technical implementation it's also your job to talk them out of it. If you're unable to talk them out of it, everyone gets what they deserve (security holes for the client, mind bogglingly stupid code for you).

Comment: Yup I tried many times also argued with my employer and told him that this is the most stupid idea ever. But the only feedback I got was "Just finish this project and client will soon find out about this problem and they will be force to make a version 2 of this because of the security problem". I gave them all the cons of the suggestion and process they want but they won't listen to any idea i give.

Comment: Good on you, and my sincerest condolences. Stupid code and security holes it is then. Or just store the *user ids* in plain text, at least that makes the code simpler.

Comment: Yeah your right. I'm thinking of adding a new column that will contain just the pin and encrypt it with Crypt::encrypt so that I can easily decrypt it whenever I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Create  your own Request  class  (ther is tutorial about that https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/12)
and in   request class you  can  use 
something like  that

```
return [

        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|unique:users', ]
```

Comment: I already created my own Password validation but what I want is to check the password if its existing.